# Objective C two errors pngcrush

Tags: objective-c

I don't have any problems with my code, but I think there are some settings wrong.
On the simulator, my application works great, but when I want to put it on my device I get the following error:

```
**pngcrush caught libpng error**

Could not find file: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJ-afhreiqghfsdvwbrdbfrawtkuser/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PROJ.app/Email.png
```

This is the first error I get, and it only happens with Mail.png and Emailp.png. All other pics are okay.

The second error I get is not really an error. But when I view the .app folder which is on my device, I have lots of files which shouldn't be in there:

```
AppDelegate.d
Appdelegate.dia
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.o
Proj-Prefix.pch
```

I have these for every header. How can I change it so it won't all land in my bundle?

Comment: It sounds like you have been adding and deleting files from your project a bit. I suggest you delete the app in the simulator and on your device, do a clean in Xcode, `Shift` + `⌘` + `K`, and then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gessing that Email.png has not been linked to your target when you imported the image, thus it has not been moved to your device.
You can check if you select the blue area with the project's name in the navigator window and go to Build Phases -> Copy Boundle Resources and add it with the little plus sign at the bottom if it's not in the list.

My other guess is that the actual filename is email.png and while the simulator is case-insensitive, the device is not. That can be why it cannot find it.

**EDIT:**
**2,** I'm quite certain XCode generates those files at build time and somehow they got put in the .app package. Can you tell us what's inside those files?